# How do I override InternalResourceViewResolver in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ioc

I want to override `InternalResourceViewResolver` or `ViewResolver` in Springboot project. Anybody have any idea about it?

Any suggestions please?

EDIT: I have already tried this solution.

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: Better code formatting

Answer (score 1):

According this section of [Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-view-resolvers), `InternalResourceViewResolver` has by default name `defaultViewResolver`, so you just need to register yours under the same name.

Comment: I tried to override it using defaultViewResolver but it doesn't work for me.